# Wordpress background-image

Tags: php, wordpress

Какую функцию нужно прописать для блока, имеющего `background-image`, чтобы из настроек темы *wordpress* можно было менять `background-image`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы можно было установить фоновое изображение, нужно включить поддержку такого изображения для темы. Делается это функцией `add_theme_support('custom-background')`. После включения возможности в кастомайзере можно будет установить фоновое изображение.